# for loop to insert in mails table

Tags: oracle, plsql

```
-set serveroutput ON
```

Write a PL/SQL block to insert numbers into the mails table. a)Insert the numbers 1 through 10, excluding 6 and 8.  b)Commit before the end of the block

```
BEGIN
  FOR l_counter IN 1..10
  LOOP
    insert into mails
    VALUES (i);
    --continue WHEN 6 AND 8;
  END LOOP;
  commit;
END;
```

Answer (score 4):

You could do

```
BEGIN
  FOR n IN 1..10 LOOP
    IF n NOT IN (6,8) THEN
      insert into mails
      VALUES (n);
    END IF;
  END LOOP;

  commit;
END;
```

or you could just say

```
INSERT INTO MAILS
  SELECT LEVEL
    FROM DUAL
    WHERE LEVEL NOT IN (6,8)
    CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 10
```

Or there's always

```
MERGE INTO MAILS m
  USING (SELECT LEVEL AS N
           FROM DUAL
           WHERE LEVEL NOT IN (6,8)
           CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 10) d
    ON (m.VAL = d.N)
  WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
    INSERT VALUES (N);
```

[db<>fiddle here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=f970f73da50c5848e5a9b0082a558a31)

Comment: good catch..! When I considered  `connect by level <= 10 and level not in (6,8)` which failed and I gave up this option without a subquery, now see you took into `where`clause...

Answer (score 1):

Indeed, you don't need a PL/SQL Block, using an SQL-Insert is enough such as

```
SQL> insert into mails
select * from
(
  select level as lvl
    from dual
 connect by level <= 10
)
where lvl not in (6,8);

SQL> commit;
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you need below -

```
BEGIN
  FOR l_counter IN 1..10
  LOOP
    IF l_counter IN (6, 8) THEN
        CONTINUE;
    END IF;
    insert into mails
    VALUES (l_counter);
  END LOOP;
  commit;
END;
```